# depricated issues while installing gatsby by npm

Tags: gatsby, npm-install

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

I used npm install to install gatsby-cli (npm-v: 8.1.2) but

```
> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'

changed 575 packages, and audited 576 packages in 20s

108 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 5 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

got these errors. What is the problem and how do I solve them?

Answer (score 0):

The output you've shared are warnings, not errors. They will never break your site or your application.

They are deprecation warning about some dependencies that Gatsby uses internally and normally the team should be well aware of. They appear because some of them need an upgrade that may contain breaking changes so they should be bumped in the next Gatsby releases in order to check the stability of the framework (if they need to be). You don't have to worry about them, they are "normal" and they don't mean any security leak

As I said, if you upgrade it manually, you can potentially break your dependency tree.

You can run:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

The audit command submits a description of the dependencies configured in your project to your default registry and asks for a report of known vulnerabilities. If any vulnerabilities are found, then the impact and appropriate remediation will be calculated. If the fixed argument is provided, then remediations will be applied to the package tree.

In the case of `@hapi/joi@`, there's an open [pull-request](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/25797) that fixes it but as I said if there's any potential thread/vulnerability issue will be fixed in the next releases

You can read [@LekoArts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10164092/lekoarts) (Gatsby staff) response in this [npm warning topic](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/34409):

> While those audit messages might seem scary they are almost always
> irrelevant in the context of Gatsby as it's a build tool. So there is
> nothing to "fix" as the warning is not relevant.
>
> Gatsby creates static assets and runs everything at build time and not
> during runtime. `npm audit` is designed for runtime / Node apps so it
> flags issues that can occur there. This means that almost every
> "vulnerability" report we receive are false positives. While in
> principle Gatsby can also have vulnerabilities you need to make sure
> that it's relevant to Gatsby before reporting it. For example a "Regex
> DDOS attack" can never be a real vulnerability for a development-time
> tool. If you want to override/update a transitive dependency you can
> use [yarn resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/).
>
> You can also read [npm audit: Broken by Design](http://npm%20audit:%20Broken%20by%20Design) to learn more about
> this.
>
> If you know that a vulnerability affects Gatsby because you understand
> what the vulnerability is, please report it [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/SECURITY.md). Thanks!

Related threads:

- https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25764

Comment: If the error is irrelevant, then do you know why gatsby isn't installed?
`Run `npm audit` for details.
❯ gatsby --help
zsh: command not found: gatsby
`
this is the next part of my terminal window, and it seems gatsby isn't installed

Comment: Warnings can't break the installation. Share more details about the console output because it seems that Gatsby isn't installed indeed, there should be an error somewhere

Comment: There aren't any other outputs / npm -v: 8.1.2, node -v: v16.13.1

Answer (score -1):

to those who have the same problem: I downgraded node to 14.18.2?? and it worked I guess it is a compatibility problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).